# What kind of Context onAttach gets

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

Say me pls what kind of context `onAttach` gets in a `Fragment`? Activity or application?

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get Activity context to which the fragment is attached to.
You can check it by isInstance  in Java

Answer (score 0):

The context you get in onAttach is the activity that contains the fragment